# EF Core Many to Many with Identity User not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

So if I understand correctly, EF Core 5.0 updated how to make your many to many relationship. I wanted to try this out using IdentityUser & Tournament classes. Here is the code that I have.

**Tournament Class:**

```
public class Tournament
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }

   public ICollection<AppUser> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

**IdentityUser Class**
(I have tried to set the id as int too)

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Tournament> RegisteredTournaments;
}
```

**In my Startup class:**

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
```

**And lastly, my DbContext class** (AppUsers out of comments changes nothing)

```
 public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
 {
    //public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
       base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

But now, when I add this migration, it will only add a FK 'TournamentId' into the AspNetUsers table. Anything I can do to properly implement this?

Thanks in advance,
Janne

Comment: Make the *field* `public ICollection<Tournament> RegisteredTournaments;` *property*  ( add `{ get; set; }` at the end), otherwise it is not recognized as navigation property automatically.

Comment: wow okay that did it, thank you!